# Duplicate pages indexed in Google

Tags: google-index

I did a small coding mistake and Google indexed my site incorrectly.

This is the correct form: https://www.foo.com/urunler/171/TENGA-CUP-DOUBLE-HOLE

But Google indexed my site like this: https://www.foo.com/urunler/171/cart.aspx

First I fixed the problem and made a site map with only the correct link in it.  Now I checked webmaster tools and I see this:

```
Total indexed 513 Not selected 544 Blocked by robots 0
```

So I think this can be caused by double indexes, and it looks like the pages not selected makes the correct pages not indexed. I want to know how to fix the "https://www.foo.com/urunler/171/cart.aspx" links. Should I fix in code or should I connect to Google to re-index my site?

If I should redirect wrong/duplicate links to correct ones, how should that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing all your links go to correct canonical URLs, then you should set up 301 redirects from the erroneous pages to the canonical URL. This will immediately fix all the links for users following incorrect links in the SERPs, and over time Google will correct the links in the SERPs.

Comment: do I have to use 301 page or can I redirect to correct one at pageload?

Comment: I used this code; HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "correct URL"));